# Vegas file exchange with Pro Tools

Tags: vegas, pro-tools

I have an audio post gig for an indy film that I just picked up and the editor is using Vegas.

I've been looking around and I can't seem to find detailed or clear information about Vegas' export/exchange options.

What format(s) does it support... OMF, AAF, MXF, BXF, XML?

Does anyone have a workflow or advice for exchanging between the two?

Any positive experiences or horror stories?

Oh, and for posterity in case anyone has any suggestions, I'm on an Intel Mac with Pro Tools 9. I also have Reaper, Logic, Premiere and Final Cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an absurd amount of research for such a simple thing I basically found out that Vegas will export AAF and Pro Tools 9 should be able to import it.

I'd still love to hear if there are any known issues, settings preferences or workflows.

Cheers!